# optimize.minimize with SLSQP not converging, even when the result is less than ftol. Does anyone know why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm using the following function:

```
result=optim.minimize(fun,x0,method='SLSQP',options={'eps': 0.0001, 'ftol': 1000},bounds=[(0,0.01)],args=(file,)).

def fun(opt_vars,file):
    # ## Known Vals
    v=np.zeros(5)
    v[0]=454.546412
    v[1]=3242.201274
    v[2]=1000023
    v[3]=5.2 
    v[4]=1.1
    output=myfunction(opt_vars,file)
    return abs((v[0]-output[0])/v[0] + (v[1]-output[1])/v[1] +  (v[2]-output[2])/v[2] + (v[3]-output[3])/v[3] + (v[4]-output[4])/v[4])
```

Fun is a normalized costing function that produces values of about 1.28e-4. I've tried values of `ftol` ranging from 1000 to 1e-4 and the optimizer doesn't converge. I can't understand why. From the documentation, `xtol` can't be set, so this can't be the reason for this. I'm not sure if this is an error to do with the minimize function or whether this is me misusing the function. As 1.28e-4 satisfies `ftol = 1000`, I can't see why the solution doesn't converge immediately.

Steps taken to debug:

1. Reading the documentation
2. Trying to use xtol
3. Setting different values of ftol
4. Asking Bing chat for help
5. Posting on the github page, in which they referred me here

Comment: maybe your cost function is *really* like that. Can you post a working example of your cost function? (i.e.. what does `myfunction` inside your `fun` look like?)

Comment: But surely if the condition for termination is satisfied, wouldn't the function just terminate? Is there another termination condition that hasn't been satisfied?

Comment: That's not a [minimal **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As cmbfast already mentioned, your `myfunction` is missing. We need a code snippet that we can copy and paste. Otherwise, it's hard to help properly as our mind-reading skills are limited :P. That being said, using `abs` inside an objective function is a sin of numerical (nonlinear) optimization.